# While building the javascript bundle on expo developer tools, I got an errorr: Unable to resolve "firebase" from "Fire.js"

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

Here's how I imported the file in "Fire.js"
[import statement in fire.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwn3w.png)

[And this is the error I'm getting on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzUuI.jpg)

Comment: Please improve your question by adding screenshots of the error and try to provide more details about your error!

Comment: Screenshot added. Please help me to resolve this problem